# python pandas read_excel engine=openpyxl not closing file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, file-handling

I am loading a dataframe into pandas using following:

```
import pandas as pd

df_factor_histories=pd.read_excel("./eco_factor/eco_factor_test_data_builder.xlsx",
                                  engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=0)
```

`engine=openpyxl` is required to enable `read_excel` to support newer Excel file formats (specifically in my case `.xlsx` rather than jusy `.xls`).

The dataframe loads just fine ***but the file is left open***:

```
import psutil

p = psutil.Process()
print(p.open_files())

OUTPUT
[popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\xx\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite', fd=-1), 
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1), 
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\kernel32.dll.mui', fd=-1), 
popenfile(path='D:\\xxxxx\\data modelling\\eco_factor\\eco_factor_test_data_builder.xlsx', fd=-1)]
```

This [Github Post](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29803) suggests the bug is fixed - but not for me (running Anaconda/Jupyter).
Relevant versions I am running:

```
numpy                         1.19.2
openpyxl                      3.0.5
pandas                        1.1.3
Python 3.7.4
```

**I would appreciate some suggestions on how to close the files/best work around this, thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to remove `engine='openpyxl'` from your code. It isn't actually needed. I use the `pd.read_excel` without it and it works just fine even for `.xlsx` format.

Removing this will cause the default behavior for the engine parameter to take over. The engine will know which engine to use:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel

```
engine : str, default None
If io is not a buffer or path, this must be set to identify io. Supported engines: “xlrd”, “openpyxl”, “odf”, “pyxlsb”. Engine compatibility :

“xlrd” supports old-style Excel files (.xls).

“openpyxl” supports newer Excel file formats.

“odf” supports OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt).

“pyxlsb” supports Binary Excel files.

Changed in version 1.2.0: The engine xlrd now only supports old-style .xls files. When engine=None, the following logic will be used to determine the engine:

If path_or_buffer is an OpenDocument format (.odf, .ods, .odt), then odf will be used.

Otherwise if path_or_buffer is an xls format, xlrd will be used.

Otherwise if openpyxl is installed, then openpyxl will be used.

Otherwise if xlrd >= 2.0 is installed, a ValueError will be raised.

Otherwise xlrd will be used and a FutureWarning will be raised. This case will raise a ValueError in a future version of pandas.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the supplementary info - it works on my current application but I found myself including it in another application a few days ago because `.xlsx` would not load without that - I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue,

When i read the excel file using pandas with `engine=openpyxl`. It is not being closed. when i try to archive/ move the excel file using python, it was giving error,

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Also, once it is read by pandas, we are not able to edit or any other operation on excel file using Excel tool.

Following solution worked for me.
i am using:

```
python version 3.6.8.
```

> pandas==0.25.1
>
> openpyxl==3.0.7

```
import io
import pandas as pd

with open('path/to/input_excel_file.xlsx', "rb") as f:
    file_io_obj = io.BytesIO(f.read())


df_input_file = pd.read_excel(file_io_obj, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=None)
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't appear to solve the original question (not closing the file once opened with pandas), but this one does.